# Sublists of list in F#

Tags: list, f#, linked-list

How to get sublists

```
[1]; [1; 2]; [1; 2; 3]; ...; [1; 2; 3; ...; n]
```

from list

```
[1; 2; 3; ...; n]
```

by the most idiomatic way? All that I could is:

```
List.scan (fun acc elem -> elem::acc) [] [1;2;3;4;5]
> val it : int list list =
    [[]; [1]; [2; 1]; [3; 2; 1]; [4; 3; 2; 1]; [5; 4; 3; 2; 1]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: don't know if there is an idiomatic way but yours is fine (just add a map to reverse the lists) - btw: it's called `heads` ;)

Comment: there are far more sublists ;)

Comment: I was talking about `List.scan (fun acc elem -> elem::acc) [] [1;2;3;4;5] |> List.map List.rev |> List.tail`

Comment: doh my bad ... it's probably called **inits**  not * heads*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your implementation is fine.  Here is my alternative:

```
let source = [1..10]

let counts = [0..source.Length] // Or start at 1 if you don't want to start with an empty list

counts |> List.map (fun count -> source |> List.take count)
```

Comment: the OP's version is much better though

Comment: @Carsten, why do you say that? To me this is simpler. It iterates over the input list twice but only creates each output sublist once because no reverse is needed.

Comment: it will call `take` *n-times* too

Comment: it's just a matter of taste - for me the OP's answer is just closer to the way you would do it if performance was relevant (using *snoc*-lists) - if you are fine with ignoring the wrong order (and ignore/don't use the `List.map List.rev`) it's just the better option

Answer (score 4):

Throwing mine onto the pile, which is maybe a refinement of Foole's answer:

```
let inits list =
    list |> List.mapi (fun i _ -> List.take (i + 1) list)
```

`mapi` is a useful function: You provide it a function which takes the each index and item.

Comment: I cannot find `take` method in the `List` module

Comment: It only exists in F# 4.0 and later. You can add it to the list module with this: `module List = let take n l = Seq.take n l |> Seq.toList`. I've only put it on one line because this is a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another one:

```
let f n = List.init n (fun i -> [1..(i + 1)])
```

List.init exists for the task of initializing a list.